# React Native app unable to correctly open web links to Google Docs on Android

Tags: android, react-native, google-docs, deep-linking

I'm working on a React Native app which will include links to many different websites. Users should be able to click on the link and be taken to the correct location. However, currently links to Google Docs are not working correctly on Android (haven't tested on iOS). When the user clicks on one of the links, it displays an error. If they try to open it through the Docs app, the error says "Document lookup failed. It is possible the document was deleted.". If they try to open it through Chrome, it says "Sorry, the file you have requested does not exist." Importantly, if you take the link URL and paste it into the Chrome search bar, it correctly displays the document.

Here's how I am doing the linking:

```
import { Linking } from 'react-native';

const onPress = async () => {
    let link = url.toLowerCase();
    if (!/^https?:\/\//.test(link) && !/^mailto:/.test(link)) {
        link = `https://${link}`;
    }
    Linking.openURL(link);
};
```

Android Manifest.xml includes the following:

```
<manifest ...>
    ...
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    ...
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="https"/>
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="http"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>
```

Version information:

```
react-native: 0.66.5 (yes, I know I need to upgrade, but I'm not sure if it will fix this issue)
minSdkVersion = 21
compileSdkVersion = 33
targetSdkVersion = 33
```

I've checked that the link the app is trying to open is correct. I've also tried looking through the [react-native Linking documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking#canopenurl) and the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#Browser) but I've followed all the relevant instructions in the react-native Linking documentation and it seems to me like the Android documentation is primarily focused on incoming deep links, not outgoing ones.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here I am answering my own question less than 24 hours after posting. It's so easy to miss the most obvious solutions when coding.

The issue here is that I was making the entire URL lowercase before trying to open it. I originally added that part of the code because I wanted to make the scheme lowercase and I forgot that some URLs would have identifiers with both lowercase and uppercase letters, so making the entire URL lowercase changes the identifier.

After modifying this code to make just the scheme lowercase, I was able to correctly open Google Docs links.